# Python opencv videocapture can't read exist normal file

Tags: python, opencv, video, dataset, google-colaboratory

I use colab with google drive to train video classification model.

My dataset has 50gb with 100000 files

Here is my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(read_path)
while True:
    isOpen, img = cap.read()
    if isOpen == False:
        break
    img = cv2.resize(img,(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT))
    frame_list.append(img)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
frames = np.array(frame_list)
```

The above code is in the torch dataset

dataloader(train_set,batchsize = 16, pin_memory=True,num_workers=8,shuffle=True)

When I read videos, some video return len(frames) with 0

The codec for my video is DIVX

How can I fix it?

All read_path are similar like

"/content/drive/Mydrive/trainging/day04-a-5/a_4/001.mp4"

"/content/drive/Mydrive/trainging/day04-a-5/a_4/002.mp4"

"/content/drive/Mydrive/trainging/day05-b-5/b_4/001.mp4"

And all files exist and are normal

Only a small part of my dataset randomly occurs this issue

I didn't know what occur this issue.

Comment: You may look for tools for [checking the integrity of a video file](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4). Try reading 100 frames using `cap.read()` until breaking the loop. In case you need help, please share a problematic video file.